Statistical test for frequency counts?
I have data of customer purchases over time. Certain clusters of purchases tend to occur together within a short timeframe for each customer. One customer can have multiple clusters of purchases. I have basically classified these clusters of purchases (not customers) into two groups (by their regularity or irregularity).
This is an example of the data. Both groups have equal number of clusters of purchases, say 30000 each. Group A has 120 clusters with pasta it in and group b has 140. From this there were 600 purchases of pasta in group A and 4000 for group B.



product
Group_A cluster
Group_B cluster
Group_A frequency
Group_B frequency




pasta
120
140
600
4000


cheese






...







I want to know which specific products are significant in distinguishing between the two groups. I plan to compare the frequency of each product in the two groups. Is there a statistical test that can tell us if the difference in frequency for a product is significant between the two groups?
Any advice is appreciated.

Instead of a statistical test of frequencies, you may want to start with correspondence analysis http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis which uncovers patterns and structures in categorical data based on spectral decomposition of a suitably transformed table. It is essentially a discrete version of the principal component analysis. See tutorials (1) simple correspondence analysis for a contingency table of 2 categorical variables http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/113-ca-correspondence-analysis-in-r-essentials/ and (2) multiple correspondence analysis for >2 categorical variables http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/114-mca-multiple-correspondence-analysis-in-r-essentials/.
